# using jquery <a> tag click event want to fire but not working

Tags: jquery

```
<a class="modal" id="fblogin_pop" rel="{size: {x: 450, y: 400}, ajaxOptions: {method: \'get\'}}" href="#fblogin_btn">fblogin</a>
```

this is my link tag and click on that open popup for facebook login. now i want to trigger this event on pageload if user is not login for this i make this code. but those popup not open.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('#fblogin_pop').click();
});
```

please help me if any one also faced this issue and have idea to short out.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try with .ready instead of .load?

Comment: First of all, just try some debug : 
`jQuery(window).load(function() {
  console.log(jQuery('#fblogin_pop'));
  jQuery('#fblogin_pop').click();
});`

Comment: do you want to open a modal on window.load()

Comment: yes i want to open modal on window.load()

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fblogin_pop').click();
});
```

or

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#fblogin_btn').modal('show');
 });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("fblogin_pop").click();

});
```

One of the Above should work fine. and your href and ID given to anchor looks like interchanged. cross check

Comment: sorry but click on that a tag we have to open facebook login popup those code in div which id i passed in href. if i remove those then nothing should happen

Comment: Wait i will edit my answer to do that. it will work fine then

Comment: Changed my Answer pls check and tell me which one worked fine for you. i will keep only that block and remove other.

Answer (score 0):

To open popup modal on window.load() just use following jquery code.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#yourModalId').modal('show');
});
```

`#yourModalId` refers your modal.

Check this demo on your localhost -

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#fblogin_pop').modal('show');   // Simple way to open modal on window.load();

/* Alternative way using trigger click function
      $('a').trigger('click');
*/

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fblogin_pop" rel="{size: {x: 450, y: 400}, ajaxOptions: {method: \'get\'}}">FB Login</a>
<div id="fblogin_pop" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope, this might work for u. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('#fblogin_pop').trigger( "click" );
```